# TypeScript: How to cast an HTMLAnchorElement property from an EventTarget inference?

Tags: typescript

The example below is in VanillaJS. I think TypeScript is making the wrong type inference on the `target` property. The code does work so `id` is definitely there.

I'm not sure how to cast a property on another object. Can it be done, and if so an example would help, thanks.

```
const findClickedTab = (tabArray: string[], event: MouseEvent): string | false => {
  // error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'
  const clickedTab: string[] = tabArray.filter(tabId => tabId === event.target.id); 

  // MouseEvent
  console.log(event.constructor.name, `=====event.constructor.name=====`); 

  // HTMLAnchorElement
  console.log(event.target.constructor.name, `=====event.target.constructor.name=====`); 

  if (clickedTab[0]) {
    return clickedTab[0];
  } else return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using `as` keyword:

```
const findClickedTab = (tabArray: string[], event: MouseEvent): string | false => {
  // casts target from EventTarget to HTMLAnchorElement
  const clickedTab: string[] = tabArray.filter(tabId => tabId === (event.target as HTMLAnchorElement).id);
};
```

Comment: You would wrap the part you wish to cast in brackets with the cast if you wanted to do it on one line.